# How do I echo the financial year?

Tags: php, date, calendar

I am new to PHP and I have a question on how to echo a financial year.

For echo of calendar year, I use:

```
<?php echo date("y"); ?>
```

My financial year starts on 1 July of the previous calendar year and concludes on 30 June, and I want to echo the financial year.

I have no any idea how I can do it. I searched for answers to this problem but I cannot find an easy solution for me.

**Expected output**

If it is sometime in June 2015, I want to print `2015` as the year, and it would then print `2016` starting on the first day of the following month.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try something like:

```
if ( date('m') > 6 ) {
    $year = date('Y') + 1;
}
else {
    $year = date('Y');
}
```

Short hand notation:

```
$year = ( date('m') > 6) ? date('Y') + 1 : date('Y');
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
if (date('m') <= 6) {//Upto June 2014-2015
    $financial_year = (date('Y')-1) . '-' . date('Y');
} else {//After June 2015-2016
    $financial_year = date('Y') . '-' . (date('Y') + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That should be simple enough, something like:

```
if (date('m') <= 6) {
    $year = date('Y');
} else {
    $year = date('Y') + 1;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an single expression that maps the month to a zero/one value depending on whether it's in the first or second half of the calendar year, then adds that to your calendar year:

```
$year = date('Y') + (int)((date('m') - 1) / 6);
```

Answer (score 2):

Its too Simple

```
if (date('m') >= 6) {
    $year = date('Y') + 1;
} else {
    $year = date('Y');
}
```

try this one!

Answer (score 1):

For India,financial year start from April of every Year.

Mostly in FY 2019-20 format

For that use following code:

```
//for current date month  used *** date('m')

    $date=date_create("2019-10-19");

    echo "<br> Month: ".date_format($date,"m");
    if (date_format($date,"m") >= 4) {//On or After April (FY is current year - next year)
        $financial_year = (date_format($date,"Y")) . '-' . (date_format($date,"y")+1);
    } else {//On or Before March (FY is previous year - current year)
        $financial_year = (date_format($date,"Y")-1) . '-' . date_format($date,"y");
    }

    echo "<br> FY ".$financial_year;

// O/P : FY 2019-20
```

Answer (score 1):

Function based input date parameter thats return financial year and you can define format also....

```
function getFinancialYear($inputDate,$format="Y"){
    $date=date_create($inputDate);
    if (date_format($date,"m") >= 4) {//On or After April (FY is current year - next year)
        $financial_year = (date_format($date,$format)) . '-' . (date_format($date,$format)+1);
    } else {//On or Before March (FY is previous year - current year)
        $financial_year = (date_format($date,$format)-1) . '-' . date_format($date,$format);
    }

    return $financial_year;
}
```

use example :

```
echo getFinancialYear("2021-12-13","Y");//2021-2022

echo getFinancialYear("2021-12-13","y");//21-22
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some single liner code for getting financial year in php

4 Digit Format

```
echo date("m") >= 4 ? date("Y"). '-' . (date("Y")+1) : (date("Y") - 1). '-' . date("Y");
//Will return 2022-2023 as per current year
```

2 Digit Format

```
echo date("m") >= 4 ? date("y"). '-' . (date("y")+1) : (date("Y") - 1). '-' . date("y");
//Will return 22-23 as per current year
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply call:

```php
echo date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 6+date('m')));
```

As per the docs of [mktime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php):

> The number of the month relative to the end of the previous year. Values 1 to 12 reference the normal calendar months of the year in question. Values less than 1 (including negative values) reference the months in the previous year in reverse order, so 0 is December, -1 is November, etc. Values greater than 12 reference the appropriate month in the following year(s).

Adding 6 to the current month shifts to your expected financial year.

Comment: I don't think this is right. If my financial year starts in April (not July like the OP) then I'd swap `6` for `3`. Assuming we're currently in January 2019 then `$m = 1` but `echo date('Y', mktime(0, 0, 0, 3+$m));` outputs `2019` when it should output `2018` until the end of March 2019. https://ideone.com/f010Lx